# Simple SQL Query

Tags: count

I have a db that in one column have 5 possible values: "Fechado", "Aberto", "Em Despiste", "Cancelado", "Resolvido".

And im trying to do a query that counts the values to a json file

```
var data = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM graficos WHERE ESTADO='FECHADO'";
```

I've tried this and it gives me `[{"":189}]`. How can i get the count of the other values ?

I think that this is a simple question but i can't reach it...It is possible to have the count of the other values on the same query ?

Comment: I'm not seasoned in this SE site. But this doesn't seem like a question for DBA's. More like a question for developers. Stackoverflow seems like a better fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a list and then resolve it in code, if you like.

```
SELECT ESTADO, COUNT(*) CNT 
FROM graficos 
WHERE ESTADO IS NOT NULL -- Discounting NULL values, if any
GROUP BY ESTADO
```

This will return a list of each distinct ESTADO value, and the number of rows containing that value in graficos table.